# TypeError while handling missing data using SimpleImputer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I am trying to handle the missing data in my dataset using SimpleImputer from sklearn.imputer and my code is as follows :

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', verbose=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

and when imputer.fit line is executed I get the following TypeError :

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> '(slice(0, None, None), slice(1, 3, None))' is an invalid key

Answer (score 0):

The above error can be resolved by using iloc/loc as follows :

```
 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', verbose=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X.iloc[:,1:3])
X.iloc[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X.iloc[:,1:3])
```

This works now!